# Get Date information in android

Tags: android

How to get the phone's date,month,year in android ?

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: Please use the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+%2B+get+system+date+and+time) feature before posting new questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just fetch all this from the obove declared stuff

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above code, and it works fine.
However i recently noticed that when i convert the int's to
a string to show the date format as UK, the months were always out by one.

i.e Febuary was showing as '01' March as '02' etc.

When reading the documentation on calender, i realised that the months start at 0 and end at 11.

So i had to modify the code as follows to show date as correct UK format..

```
//Get Current date and set as text
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      int day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
      int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);  //0 = JAN / 11 = DEC
      int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

      month=month+1; //Set int to correct month numeral, i.e 0 = JAN therefore set to 1.

      if (month<=9)  { MONTH$ = "0"+month   ;}
      else {MONTH$ = ""+month;               }    //Set month to MM


     DDMMYYYY = ""+day+"/"+MONTH$+"/"+year;    //Put date ints into string DD/MM/YYYY
```

I Hope this helps anyone else using the above code to get correct date